# pdf generator does not use new phone number

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs, pdf

Entered new phone number, used pdf generator to preview.

Old phone number is shown in the top right corner of both the PDF genrated document and the HTML view.

This is still reproducible, old question was deleted ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242860/pdf-generator-does-not-use-new-phone-number?noredirect=1#comment794329_242860 )

Reproduce steps:

1. Click apply, ensure that new phone number is entered.
2. Click "next: your resume"
3. Click "X" to delete old resume
4. Click "Attach New"
5. Click "Create from profile"
6. See old phone number is in the document.

I don't see how this is happening. It's like a server-side document cache, transaction failure, or something like that.

This is just a flat GET request to the resource, so something is already stored incorrectly somewhere before I even get to the page.

```
curl 'http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/64685/export/save-pdf-for-job/[redactedID]?mode=apply' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Accept: ...' 
-H 'Referer: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/widgets/resume?jobid=.... ' 
-H 'Cookie: ....'
-H 'Connection: keep-alive'
 --compressed
```

I know the new number is persisted *somewhere* because it's there when I come back to the field to type it in, even months later on a new device.

I also know it's been posted to the system, because this is what happens on step "2" of my reproduce list.

```
curl 'http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/widgets/apply' 
-H 'Cookie: ...'
-H 'Origin: http://careers.stackoverflow.com'
-H 'Accept-Encoding: ...'
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-H 'Accept: ...'
-H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' 
-H 'Referer: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/widgets/apply?jobId=...&applyAnonymously=False&reset=False'
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
--data 'fkey=[...]&JobId=[job id]&ReturnUrl=[referer]&Referrer=careers.stackoverflow.com&CandidateName=[my name]&CandidateEmail=[my email]&CandidatePhoneNumber=[my new phone number]&CandidateLocation=[my city]&CoverLetter=[my entire cover letter] 
--compressed
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When applying to a job, the "About you" section is pre-populated with the details from your profile, if you have one. 
However, updating this form will only affect the summary sent to the employer: it won't update your profile.

Yet, the auto-generated resume is created from your profile. That's why it doesn't include your updated phone number. You need to update your phone number *in your profile* first.

Now this is not ideal.

Even though it seems highly unlikely that someone would want a different phone number sent through the application than appears on their resume, it is also kind of weird if the application fields are treated as profile edit fields.

We are going to find a design that is more intuitive, and (maybe) allow the application form to update your profile.

Thanks a lot for your report!

Comment: Ahh, the phone number being edited by clicking *that* link was not obvious as there was no phone number on the page before editing. Thanks!